# Oracle - conditional on first row of each group

Tags: oracle, conditional-statements, grouping

**Edit** - On Oracle 11 & 12.

Say I have:

```
ID | Name | Type
----------------
1  | AAA  | 1
2  | AAA  | 2
3  | AAA  | 3
4  | BBB  | 2
5  | BBB  | 3
6  | CCC  | 1
7  | CCC  | 2
```

And I only want to return a distinct list of `Names` where `Type = 1` like so:

```
Name | Type
-----------
AAA  | 1
CCC  | 1
```

I can't find a way to select the names where the first entry for each name has a type of `1`.

Comment: Which version of Oracle ?

Comment: @APC We run 11 & 12. Updated post

Comment: What do you mean by **first** entry for a given name? **First** according to what ordering? (And please don't say "the order they are in the table" - you know that doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, type
FROM yourtable
WHERE type = 1
```

Comment: This finds all the occurrences of `type = 1`. It works with the provided sample data. However it doesn't address the requirement " to select the names where the first entry for each name has a type of 1." But as the OP has accepted this answer presumably that requirement doesn't matter. Ho hum.

Comment: @APC I agree, however as with a lot of questions on here you only get half a sample and half a requirement with the rest hidden/not shown, i presume this was used as part of a larger answer or gave the OP a push in the right direction to find their own answer. Nevertheless yours is a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

> "select the names where the first entry for each name has a type of `1`"

Let's assume ID indicates order of entry. Therefore we want to find all records where the record with the lowest ID for each NAME has TYPE = 1.

This approach uses analytic function ROW_NUMBER() to score the occurrence of TYPE with NAME. It will work on 11g and 12c.

```
with subq as (
    select name
           , type
           , row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as rn
    from your_table
   )
select name
       , type
from subq
where type = 1
and rn = 1
```

This next approach will work on 12c only. Included because MATCH_RECOGNIZE is some cool new syntax, and it would probably perform better on large amounts of data. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956)

```
select name, type
from your_table
     match_recognize (
         partition by name
         order by id
         measures first (type1.id) as t1_id
         all rows per match
         pattern ( ^type1 )
         define 
               type1 as type = 1
```

The MEASURES clause is not needed in this example, but it is useful to include `t1_id` in the projection when debugging, to confirm that the query is returning the row we're expecting.